# Передать значение URL в Iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть сайт. Сделана костылем отправка формы(СМS древняя).
Получается что форма подгружается через IFrame тот через Ajax передает php и все гуд.
Но появилась необходимость чтобы в письме указывалась страница с которой поступила заявка.
Если юзать window.location.href то он отображает ссылку Iframe.
Может как то можно передать значение в c текущем значением URL. URL- динамический

UPD - через document.referrer получается его определить.
Но как теперь передать через POST его не выходит.

```
jQuery('#feedbackForm1').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var namephone = jQuery('#namephone').val();
        var telphone = jQuery('#telphone').val('');
        var title = document.referrer;
        if (telphone != '') {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "email.php",
                data: jQuery('form#feedbackForm1').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('.feedbackForm-scs').css('opacity', 0);
                    jQuery('.sent-ok').css('opacity', 0);
                    jQuery('.feedbackForm-sc-old').fadeIn(250);
                    jQuery('.form-message-truee').fadeIn(250);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('Error. Not send.');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log('Родительское окно:' + document.referrer);
console.log('Iframe:' + location.href);
```

Comment: Да, отработал, показывает.

Comment: Да, сработал, передает рефера. Тогда еще один вопрос возник.
Задаю переменную  var myReferer = document.referrer; и хочу передать в  PHP для отправки почты. Но чет не получается

Comment: @Евгений Сафронов, я рад, что у Вас заработало. И у меня возникла необходимость поблагодарить zhurof за ответ.

Comment: @zhurof, благодарю Вас за ответ)